# Does $1 \otimes_A b= b\otimes_A 1$ imply $b \in A$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Supppse $B$ is a faithfully flat $A$-algebra, and $b$ an element in $B$. Does $1 \otimes_A b= b\otimes_A 1$ in $B\otimes_A B$ imply $b \in A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A \to B \rightrightarrows B \otimes_A B$ is exact. This is well-known. It can be proven for example as follows: The sequence is *split-exact* after tensoring with $B$ over $A$. But $B$ is faithfully flat, so this proves exactness of the original sequence.

Comment: You beat me to the answer! Just an additional remark: these are the first terms of the *Amitsur complex* of $B$ over $A$, and Martin's argument proves more generally that the whole Amitsur complex is exact.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, exactly.